# How to find multiple maximums in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to analyse some strings and compute the number of times they come up. This data is stored in a dictionary. If I were to use the max function only the first highest number encountered would be printed.

```
count = {"cow": 4, "moo": 4, "sheep": 1}
print(max(count.keys(), key=lambda x: count[x]))
cow
```

This would yield cow to be the max. How would I get "cow" and "moo" to both be printed

```
count = {"cow": 4, "moo": 4, "sheep": 1}
cow, moo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not keep it simple?

```
mx = max(count.values())
print([k for k, v in count.items() if v == mx])
# ['cow', 'moo']
```

The bracketed expression in line two is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), essentially a short hand for a `for` loop that runs over one list-like object (an "iterable") and creates a new list as it goes along. A subtlety in this case is that there are two loop variables (`k` and `v`) that run simultaneously their values being assigned by tuple unpacking (`.items()` returns pairs (key, value) one after the other). To summarize the list comprehension here is roughly equivalent to:

```
result = []
for k, v in count.items():
    if v == mx:
        result.append(k)
```

But the list comprehension will run faster and is also easier to read once you got used to it.

Comment: Thank you! Was looking at the other posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402015/print-the-key-of-the-max-value-in-a-dictionary-the-pythonic-way) but they did not seem to talk about more than one maximum. Sorry I am new to this! Could you explain how the  code in the print function works?

Answer (score 1):

Just group the counts with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), and take the maximum:

```
from collections import defaultdict

count = {"cow": 4, "moo": 4, "sheep": 1}

d = defaultdict(list)
for animal, cnt in count.items():
    d[cnt].append(animal)

print(dict(d))
# {4: ['cow', 'moo'], 1: ['sheep']}

print(max(d.items())[1])
# ['cow', 'moo']
```